# How can I get the most recent date and the Most frequently occurring values in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

How can I get the most recent date and the Most frequently occurring values in MySQL database?

I have database as the following:

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| id | Name    | idStore | Name                  | idItem | date       | price   |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 1  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.93000 |
| 2  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.98000 |
| 3  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.90000 |
| 4  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.91000 |
| 5  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.92000 |
| 6  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.92000 |
| 7  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.92000 |
| 8  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.93000 |
| 9  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.93000 |
| 10 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.94000 |
| 11 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.94000 |
| 12 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.94000 |
| 13 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.94000 |
| 14 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-28 | 0.94000 |
| 15 | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-12 | 0.98000 |
| 16 | walmart |       1 | Honeycrisp Apples     |      2 | 2011-10-22 | 1.98000 |
| 17 | walmart |       1 | Sonya Apples          |      3 | 2011-10-22 | 2.88000 |
| 18 | walmart |       1 | Gold Delicious Apples |      4 | 2011-10-22 | 0.98000 |
| 19 | walmart |       1 | Sweet Tango Apples    |      5 | 2011-10-22 | 2.48000 |
| 20 | walmart |       1 | Granny Smith Apples   |      6 | 2011-10-22 | 1.28000 |
| 21 | walmart |       1 | Fugi Apples           |      7 | 2011-10-22 | 1.38000 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

I want to get the following result:

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| id | Name    | idStore | Name                  | idItem | date       | price   |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 5  | walmart |       1 | Red Delicious Apples  |      1 | 2011-10-29 | 0.92000 |
| 16 | walmart |       1 | Honeycrisp Apples     |      2 | 2011-10-22 | 1.98000 |
| 17 | walmart |       1 | Sonya Apples          |      3 | 2011-10-22 | 2.88000 |
| 18 | walmart |       1 | Gold Delicious Apples |      4 | 2011-10-22 | 0.98000 |
| 19 | walmart |       1 | Sweet Tango Apples    |      5 | 2011-10-22 | 2.48000 |
| 20 | walmart |       1 | Granny Smith Apples   |      6 | 2011-10-22 | 1.28000 |
| 21 | walmart |       1 | Fugi Apples           |      7 | 2011-10-22 | 1.38000 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

I use the following query but it does not work because it give me all items that have the latest date

```
select id, store_name as Name, idStore, Name, idItem , max(Price.date), min(Price.price) From table group by idStore, Store.Name, idItem, Item.Name, price ORDER BY idItem ASC, date DESC;
```

I deleted the price from the grouping and get the minimum price(not the most frequently occurring)

```
select id, store_name as Name, idStore, Name, idItem , max(Price.date), min(Price.price) From table group by idStore, Store.Name, idItem, Item.Name ORDER BY idItem ASC, date DESC;
```

I am having hard time figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: This would be a typical task for a window function (`OVER` clause) in Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQL Server. But MySQL does not have that functionality.

Comment: Try making a [derived table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html) in your `FROM` clause, calling a sub-`SELECT` that gets the maximum date [or price], and then compares that "maximum value" data it found to your base table. But [use views](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/) to keep performance in check.

Comment: use distinct(idItem) while selecting

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sub-queries, the best way to optimise your request :

the first you choose max(date) & the second you filter price again

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I never get good result.
I do not use mysql frequently.

Comment: try to execute your new request in SQL area in MySQL

Comment: I am sorry. I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create table #temp
(
select max(date),Name
from tblname
group by name
)

and then make a full table scan on #temp table and get the ids from tblname where

## temp.date=tblname.date and #temp.name=tblname.date